# Fill text with an image javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I really need to fill a bold text with an image, how can i do that in javafx8?

Alternatively it would be okay to extract text from an image but i don't know how to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Set a [Text node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html)’s [fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#fillProperty) to an [ImagePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html):

```
Image image = /* ... */;

Text text = new Text("The quick brown fox");
text.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 72));
text.setFill(new ImagePattern(image,
    0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
```